# JavaScript knowledgebase, markdown wysiwyg (and back), image edit then export pdf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, laravel, markdown

We have knowledgebase (must be available for adding/editing) and if we type %ASDF% it changes this to text defined in knowledgebase in template.
I'd like to use some WYSIWYG editor if there is a need to type something manually to the report (not neccessary markdown) BUT what library/script will allow me to insert and manipulate photo (crop/resize, blur, etc) and then place it wherever I want on report by dragging and dropping (just like MS Word)?

After everything done report will be exported to PDF but i'll find some js library or other way to do that.

What will be the best framework to write this? node.js? Angular? PHP+Laravel+JS libraries? Ruby on Rails (no experience at all with ruby)? Point me please.